# How to store money/financial records in Cassandra if I can or should

Tags: mysql, transactions, cassandra

Currently I am using counters to store the customers balance. Since the counters don't have decimals, I am storing the money as cents. When customers makes a withdrawal of funds I decrement the counter and the reverse is true. Then I read that when a person reads a counter from Cassandra, you only get an estimate of the counter and not the actual figure. As a result I thought I should add MySQL to store customers account statements. Before I do this can it be done in Cassandra and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counters in Cassandra are not a good fit for the counts that must be 100% accurate, such as bank balances. The problem is that if there is a timeout exception you cannot tell if the increment was applied or not. You could use CAS in Cassandra to store counters reliably but it will be significantly slower than raw counters.

Comment: Copy that Richard. It looks like I have no other option than to bring MySql into the the gang.